# function is not visible external variable (is not defined error) - what's the issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, node-mysql

I can't understand what the error is. This is my code for `test_mysql3.js`:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var SQL_query = require('./SQL_query.js');

exports.сonnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    database: '...', 
    connectTimeout: 604800,
    multipleStatements: true
});

exports.preparingDB = function(query){
    /*console.log(query); */ 
    сonnection.query(query, function(err){
        if (err){       
            console.error('Error: ' + err.stack);
            throw err; 
        }
        console.log('Database preparation completed');
    });
};
```

There is my code for `main.js`:

```
var сonnection = require('./test_mysql3').сonnection;
/*console.log(сonnection); 

console.log(typeof(сonnection)); */
var preparingDB = require('./test_mysql3').preparingDB;

var SQL_query = require('./SQL_query.js');

before(function(done){
    /*console.log('before');*/ 
    сonnection.connect(function(err){
        if (err){
            console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connected as id ' + сonnection.threadId);
        flow.execute(function(){
            return done();
        });
    });
});

describe('Check the Email field of the registration form.', function(){
    before(function(){
        preparingDB(SQL_query.needForReg);
    });
    it('Enter an already registered Email', function(done){     
        var inputEmail = '123@ya.ru';
        var inputPassword   = '12345678Aa';
        var errElement = "//*[@class='form-errors server-error']";
        var errMessage = 'Email already in use';
        loadRegistrationForm();
        fillingRegistrationForm(inputEmail, inputPassword, errElement, errMessage);
        flow.execute(function(){
            return done();  
        });
    });
    after(function(){
        preparingDB(SQL_query.clear_db);
    });
```

About debug printing:

```
/*console.log(сonnection); 

console.log(typeof(сonnection)); */
```

It is debug printing. Now it is commented out. I wanted to check whether I'm getting the `connection` object. If you uncomment the debug print in the console displays the structure of the `connection` object and the word 'object'. I mean, I get the `connection` object.

```
/*console.log('before');*/
```

This is also a debug print. Here I wanted to check what code will be processed earlier to avoid error, when the code in `main.js` fires before the load `test_mysql3.js`. 
If you uncomment it, you can see that at first load `test_mysql3.js`, and then run the code below.

I thought that with this code there should be no problems, but when I run main.js in the console, among other things, it receives an error:

```
ReferenceError: сonnection is not defined
      at exports.preparingDB (C:\Program Files\nodejs\test\test_mysql3.js:15:2)
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\test\test4_mocha.js:34:3)
      at callFn (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:286:21)
```

I understand this error occurs due to the fact that the `preparingBD` does not see the variable `connect`. But why?? After all, it is global to the file `test_mysql.js`??? What issue???

PS.
I had rewrite part of code like:

```
before(function(done){
    preparingDB(SQL_query.needForReg);
    flow.execute(function(){
        return done();
    });
```

`Done` callback needs to wait for execution of the function. But the problem remained.

Comment: preparingDB is async. You are not waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Just a guess: you may need to use `exports.connection.query` in that `preparingDB` function

Comment: @jfriend00 
what I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: @Hans Kesting, 
'connection.query' will be called repeatedly with different queries to the database, so I wrapped it in a function, to be able to pass a parameter 'query'

Comment: Try and add a `console.log(сonnection)` just before you *use* that connection in the preparingDB function (and maybe the "before") - try and figure out *what* connection is undefined

Comment: Ok. I'm add this, like
exports.preparingDB = function(query){
 console.log(connection);
 сonnection.query(query, function(err){
  if (err){  
   console.error('Error: ' + err.stack);
   throw err; 
  }
  console.log('Database preparation completed');
 });
};

Nothing has changed, in the output in the console(